# How to print small circles in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, pdf-generation, matlab-figure

**Problem** I am trying to print small (diameter=0.02 cm etc) filled circles to pdf in exact size. I am able to print exact circles with a diameter of 2 cm, 1 cm, 0.5 cm, but when I try to go below ~0.04 cm, printed figure does not include all circles. Let me show you what I mean with some sample pictures. Note that all circles are separated by their diameter length to obtain a nice stack of them. The first image shows the output of same code with d=1, second is d=0.5 and the final one is d=0.02.

[image: d=1cm]

[image: d=0.5cm]

[image: d=0.02 cm]

First two images are correct. In the last image, you can see the most circles are not printed. Circles are in correct size but only a few of them are printed. It had to look stacked like first two pictures, but only in smaller circles.

**Minimum working example codes:**

```
cm2pts=72/2.54; %cm to inch and inch to points = cm to points
ax.Units='points'; fig.Units='points';
height=cm2pts*220; % 'page' dimensions
width=cm2pts*150;
ax.XLim=([0 width]); ax.XLim=([0 height]);
diameter=0.02*cm2pts;
distance=diameter;
...
here is a loop that creates a x,y position vector for all dots
...
plot(ax,x,y, ... 'MarkerFaceColor','black','MarkerEdgeColor','none', ...
'Marker','o','LineStyle','none','MarkerSize',diameter);
set(ax,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);
ax.Units='normalized'; ax.Position=[0 0 1 1]; ax.Units='points';
fig.PaperUnits='points';
fig.PaperPositionMode = 'manual';
fig.PaperPosition=[0 0 width height];
fig.PaperSize = [PaperPosition(3) PaperPosition(4)];
print(fig,'-painters','output.pdf','-dpdf')
```

**Notes**

-I tried up scaling everything (printing at 5x sizes, so that circles would be bigger), thinking that I would downscale (to 20%) while printing but it still failed, may be its about ratio of a circle to drawing dimensions.

-I hand checked x, y positions, they are correct.

-I tried changing marker to '.' but '.' cannot be less than ~2.5 mms even if you give MarkerSize as eps.

-I tried rectangle but it cannot be vectorized (by the means of code) therefore its slow and causes too much ram and file size.

-I tried setting figure position to real size, output did not change.

-Output file dimensions are correct in all cases.

-I tried scatter but I simply could not get the real size I wanted from scatter. It says S (marker area) is points^2 in docs for scatter but I could not get any size, for instance, d 1cm with scatter circles.

-Behaviour is same on Matlab Online.

Comment: What is the DPI setting? Is this related to circles being less than one dot?

Comment: I am using vectoral drawings so DPI should be irrelevant, right? 1 point corresponds to 0.0353 cm. You could be right about dots. Let me run some tests.

Comment: If I remember correctly, PDF uses integers for everything.

Comment: I tried dot size idea. I think it is not the direct cause. I was able to print circles with d=0.8 points to small drawings. In another example, It could not print d=25 points circles because overall drawing size is 742x525 cm. If I lower the general size to 150x100 cm then it can print. In all attempts I also made sure circle centers are at integers by the means of points. Finaly it could print d=0.5 points circles to 1x1cm drawing.

Comment: It seems to me as if there is a limiting factor/variable that produces those images. `x`, `y` and `diameter` can be correct. But it almost as if its limited by the number of circles. There are exactly 49 on the last image. Do you have such a variable in the loop as a condition or a resulting variable in your workspace?

Comment: By the way, I don't know the reason you want to draw these dots, but maybe you can use text? Write a `.` character in the right point size?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, with Matlab R2018b my pdf contains all the points. As an alternative, you could program your figures in postscript and convert that to pdf. There is even an Matlab wrapper for postscript: http://bicycle.tudelft.nl/schwab/pshacker/index.htm

Comment: @S.Chris I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. I think problem is not related to number of dots directly because you cannot print even a small number of dots if drawing is big. I'll try text.

Comment: @ｒｉｃｋｅｒｔ may I see your codes? I'll try ps.

Comment: @VolkanOzcan see my answer for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code I used for Matlab R2018b, this outputs a pfd with all the required dots.

```
fig = figure;
ax = axes;

cm2pts=72/2.54; %cm to inch and inch to points = cm to points
ax.Units='points'; fig.Units='points';
height=cm2pts*220; % 'page' dimensions
width=cm2pts*150;
ax.XLim=([0 width]); ax.XLim=([0 height]);
diameter=0.01*cm2pts;
distance=diameter;

% generate 100 by 100 dots
X = 1:100;
[x,y] = meshgrid(X,X);


% plotting
plot(ax,x,y, 'MarkerFaceColor','black','MarkerEdgeColor','none', ...
    'Marker','o','LineStyle','none','MarkerSize',diameter);

set(ax,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);
ax.Units='normalized'; ax.Position=[0 0 1 1]; ax.Units='points';
fig.PaperUnits='points';
fig.PaperPositionMode = 'manual';
fig.PaperPosition=[ 0 0 width height];
fig.PaperSize = [fig.PaperPosition(3) fig.PaperPosition(4)];
print(fig,'-painters','output.pdf','-dpdf')
```